Why does the conversion from rotation matrix to quaternion and vice-versa does not work for some matrices?
I am struggling with the conversion between some rotation matrices and vice-versa in Python and I can't seem to get what's wrong with those not working.
There are some other posts, detailing that multiple rotation matrices may be correct for a given quaternion, however the resulting rotation matrices when converting back and forth do not correspond to the same rotation, which should be the case, right?
These are the functions I wrote (with the matrix->quaternion method implemented from https://doi.org/10.2514/2.4654):

def batch_quaternions_to_rotation_matrix(w, x, y, z):
    # Normalize the quaternion
    norm = torch.sqrt(w**2 + x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
    w = w / norm
    x = x / norm
    y = y / norm
    z = z / norm
    
    # Compute the rotation matrix
    R = torch.zeros((w.shape[0], 3, 3))
    
    R[:, 0, 0] = w**2 + x**2 - y**2 - z**2
    R[:, 0, 1] = 2 * (x*y - w*z)
    R[:, 0, 2] = 2 * (x*z + w*y)
    
    R[:, 1, 0] = 2 * (x*y + w*z)
    R[:, 1, 1] = w**2 - x**2 + y**2 - z**2
    R[:, 1, 2] = 2 * (y*z - w*x)
    
    R[:, 2, 0] = 2 * (x*z - w*y)
    R[:, 2, 1] = 2 * (y*z + w*x)
    R[:, 2, 2] = w**2 - x**2 - y**2 + z**2
    
    return torch.transpose(R, 1, 2)

def batch_rotation_matrix_to_quaternions(R):
    batch_size = R.shape[0]
    K = torch.zeros((batch_size, 4, 4), dtype=R.dtype)

    K[:, 0, 0] = R[:, 0, 0] - R[:, 1, 1] - R[:, 2, 2]
    K[:, 0, 1] = R[:, 1, 0] + R[:, 0, 1]
    K[:, 0, 2] = R[:, 2, 0] + R[:, 0, 2]
    K[:, 0, 3] = R[:, 1, 2] - R[:, 2, 1]

    K[:, 1, 0] = R[:, 1, 0] + R[:, 0, 1]
    K[:, 1, 1] = R[:, 1, 1] - R[:, 0, 0] - R[:, 2, 2]
    K[:, 1, 2] = R[:, 2, 1] + R[:, 1, 2]
    K[:, 1, 3] = R[:, 2, 0] - R[:, 0, 2]

    K[:, 2, 0] = R[:, 2, 0] + R[:, 0, 2]
    K[:, 2, 1] = R[:, 2, 1] + R[:, 1, 2]
    K[:, 2, 2] = R[:, 2, 2] - R[:, 0, 0] - R[:, 1, 1]
    K[:, 2, 3] = R[:, 0, 1] - R[:, 1, 0]

    K[:, 3, 0] = R[:, 1, 2] - R[:, 2, 1]
    K[:, 3, 1] = R[:, 2, 0] - R[:, 0, 2]
    K[:, 3, 2] = R[:, 0, 1] - R[:, 1, 0]
    K[:, 3, 3] = R[:, 0, 0] + R[:, 1, 1] + R[:, 2, 2]

    K /= 3
    
    eigvals, eigvecs = torch.linalg.eig(K)
    eigvals = eigvals.real
    eigvecs = eigvecs.real

    mask = torch.logical_or(torch.isclose(eigvals,torch.ones(eigvals.shape,   dtype=eigvals.dtype)),torch.isclose(eigvals,-torch.ones(eigvals.shape, dtype=eigvals.dtype)))
    indices = torch.where(mask)
    quaternions = eigvecs[indices[0], :, indices[1]]
    return quaternions[:,3], quaternions[:,0], quaternions[:,1], quaternions[:,2]


As a benchmark, transforming a batch of (orthonormal) rotation matrices back and forth like
batch_quaternions_to_rotation_matrix(*batch_rotation_matrix_to_quaternions(rotation_matrices))
works fine for most of them, but some don't seem to work.
As an example, this rotation matrix works flawlessly:
    tensor([[[ 0.7741, -0.3551,  0.5241],
         [ 0.2347,  0.9298,  0.2834],
         [-0.5880, -0.0964,  0.8031]]])

Whereas this:
    tensor([[[-0.2643,  0.6644, -0.6991],
         [ 0.6968,  0.6327,  0.3378],
         [-0.6667,  0.3979,  0.6302]]])

does not and returns its negative instead.
    tensor([[[ 0.2643, -0.6644,  0.6991],
         [-0.6968, -0.6327, -0.3378],
         [ 0.6667, -0.3979, -0.6302]]])

I have tried a bunch of stuff already, like fixing the sign of the scalar part (multiplying the quaternion by -1 if negative), however since q_1 and -q_1 define the same rotation matrix by definition I knew beforehand that this wouldn't help.
The only feature that these uncooperative matrices share (that I can find) is the fact, that the eigenvalues in the computation of the quaternion contain a -1 instead of a 1 like the working rotations.
Other methods as implemented in different "of-the-shelf" converters also struggle with these matrices.
Unfortunately, I really need those transformations to work without this critical failure, does anybody have an idea on where a fix may lay?
Edit: The mention of the determinants by @Martin Brown got me searching and I found the solution, just adding here in case somebody has the same problem in the future:
Proper rotation matrices have a determinant of +1, and the conversions only seem to work with those. The matrices that did not work were improper rotation matrices with a determinant of -1, which could easily be fixed by multiplying one column with -1:
rotation_matrices[rotation_matrices.det() < 0,:,0] *= -1


The determinant of the working ones is +1. The problem ones have det = -1. (0.999971 in the examples cited). Might get better answers if asked on the maths section.

Well, this was actually all it took to get me on the right track, thank you so much!

Be sure that matrices are ONLY rotation matrices (no mirroring shear and etc). And verify your code by other good tested library.

The mention of the determinants by @Martin Brown got me searching and I found the solution, just adding here in case somebody has the same problem in the future:
Proper rotation matrices have a determinant of +1, and the conversions only seem to work with those. The matrices that did not work were improper rotation matrices with a determinant of -1, which could easily be fixed by multiplying one column with -1:
rotation_matrices[rotation_matrices.det() < 0,:,0] *= -1

